# What is "INTERVAL=0" means in Oracle Schedular?

Tags: oracle, intervals

My Oracle DBA have setup a task with following repeat_interval:

```
Start Date :"30/JAN/20 08:00AM"
Repeat_interval: "FREQ=DAILY; INTERVAL=0; BYMINUTE=15"
```

Can I ask what is `"Interval=0"` means?
Does it means this task will run daily from 8AM, and will repeat every 15 mins until success?

I tried to get the answer from Google, but what I find is what is Interval=1, but nothing for 0.

So would be great if anyone can share me some light here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INTERVAL is the number of increments of the FREQ value between executions. I believe in this case that a value of 0 or 1 would be the same. The schedule as shown would execute once per day (FREQ=DAILY), at approximately 15 minutes past a random hour (BYMINUTE=15, but BYHOUR and BYSECOND are not set).

Schedule has nothing to do with whether or not the previous execution succeeded or not. Start Date is only the date at which the job was enabled, not when it actually starts processing.

If you want it to run every 15 minutes from the moment you enable it, you should set as follows:

```
FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=15
```

If you want it to run exactly on the quarter hour, then this:

```
FREQ=MINUTELY; BYMINUTE=0,15,30,45; BYSECOND=0
```

If you want it to run every day at 8am, then this:

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=8; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0
```